# Test Nework Latency Using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

**Goal:** take a list of servers' external ip address. perform a ping to test latency. Like in CMD the ping command shows an average latency. But in visual studio I found the ping only as Boolean for connectivity to a server. How might I go about testing latency to a server to find the fastest connection possible in vb.net? I can't find any other way to do a ping other than. `my.computer.network.ping(192.168.1.1)`. So is there another way to accomplish a latency test in vb.net? Thanks!

**Skill Lvl:** close to absolute beginner

Answer (score 8):

Here you have a ping example for VB.NET

```
Dim host As String = "82.123.23.XX" ' use any other machine name
Dim pingreq As Ping = New Ping()
Dim rep As PingReply = pingreq.Send(host )
Console.WriteLine("Pinging {0} [{1}]", host , rep.Address.ToString())
Console.WriteLine("Reply From {0} : time={1} TTL={2}", rep.Address.ToString(), rep.RoundtripTime, rep.Options.Ttl)
```

You will need to Import

> System.Net.NetworkInformation

Answer (score 2):

```
Public Shared Function GetPingMs(ByRef hostNameOrAddress As String)
    Dim ping As New System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping
    Return ping.Send(hostNameOrAddress).RoundtripTime
End Function

GetPingMs("127.0.0.1")

GetPingMs("www.dreamincode.net")
```

Source: http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet1511.htm

Answer (score 1):

Just write this code on button click, no need to import anything.

```
Dim IP As String = InputBox("Enter Client's IP", "Ping To Client")

Shell("CMD.exe /C ping " & IP & " -t", AppWinStyle.NormalFocus)
```