# Detect ping times

Tags: vb.net

I currently have a method to see if a device is 'online' or 'offline'. I am now trying to see if there is a way to see if it is in the middle (by ping times exceeding 300~ or something similar).

**Current working code I am using for online/offline**

```
If My.Computer.Network.Ping(RouterBox.Text) Then
        'Online
        RouterPingIcon.Image = My.Resources.PingUP
    Else
        RouterPingIcon.Image = My.Resources.PingDOWN
        'Offline
    End If
```

Any ideas?

Comment: in the middle of being "online" or "offline"?  I'm not sure that's an actual state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this code ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13401797/test-nework-latency-using-vb-net)) :

```
Public Function GetPingMs(address As String) As Long
    Dim ping As New System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping
    Return ping.Send(address).RoundtripTime
End Function
```

Try [searching](http://bfy.tw/1Vkh) before asking a question...

For example :

```
If My.Computer.Network.Ping(RouterBox.Text) Then
    'Online
    If GetPingMs(RouterBox.Text) < 300 Then
        'Good ping
        RouterPingIcon.Image = My.Resources.PingUP
    Else
        'Bad ping
        RouterPingIcon.Image = My.Resources.PingMIDDLE
    End If
Else
    RouterPingIcon.Image = My.Resources.PingDOWN
    'Offline
End If
```